# For given circuit, does the current "io" through the branch equal zero after short circuit ? [2-port network]

Tags: circuit-analysis, short-circuit, port, nodal-analysis

The circuit is;

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsQ9uN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For given 2 port network, Im shorting V1 to solve for y22 and y12 and apply a current source at V2.[Y-Parameters]

This is the circuit we get;

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD9Oqz.png)</sup>

***Now my question is***; what will be `io` (current through 3-ohm resistor branch) will be equal to? Will it flow through 6-ohm resistor ? Or will it be equal to "zero"?

Comment: If you include R1 in your circuit diagram, in parallel with the short-circuit, what's the current through it?

Comment: @Chu I believe the current will flow into least resistive path, in other words will ignore 3-Ohm resistor.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @Chu So you are implying "io" will be equal to zero ? since "io" is the current through 3-ohm resistor.

Comment: Yes............

Comment: @Chu Okay understood, so if we have "io" = 0, then doesnt it mean the dependent source 2i0 will also be equal to zero ? how come dependent source(2io) will be equal to zero?

Comment: The dependent source will give zero current and will present an infinite impedance across its terminals. For example, taking a **very** simple model of a bipolar transistor, the current gain is \$\frac{I_C}{I_B}\$, if you short the base to ground, so that zero current flows into the base, then there will be zero collector current.